# Git stash issue

Tags: git, git-stash

I have an issue in git stash.

Say for example I have 3 files say `a.txt,b.txt & c.txt` in the repo and the directory is clean.

Now I'm modifying 2 files among them : `a.txt and b.txt`.

Now I havent completed my changes in thw two files so I am stashing them by the foll command:

```
$ git stash save "First Stash"
```

No if I do a `$ git stash list`, I get

```
stash@{0}: On master: First Stash
```

No if I modify the third text file `c.txt` and stash that as well as shown:

```
$ git stash save "Second Stash"
```

No finally if I do a `$git stash list` I'm getting the foll result,

```
stash@{0}: On master: Second stash
stash@{1}: On master: First Stash
```

The stash number and the messages are mixed up here.What's going on here?
 Now if i pop the `stash@{0}` I get the first stash contents but the message reversed here which is displaying as Second stash but should have  been First Stash.

**This is my work flow**

```
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> ls
a.txt  b.txt
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> echo Hello World >> a.txt
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> git stash save "First"
Saved working directory and index state On master: First
HEAD is now at cff03c6 Initail Commit
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> echo Hello World >> b.txt
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> git stash save "Second"
Saved working directory and index state On master: Second
HEAD is now at cff03c6 Initail Commit
```

**These are my available stashes:**

```
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: Second
stash@{1}: On master: First
```

**Now I''ll be trying to apply the stash@{1} which is the first stash and should apply the file a.txt**

```
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> git stash apply `stash@{1}`
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   b.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

As seen above I get the most recent changes applied.

And if i try without the ticks `` then it gives me the foll error.

```
admin:stud:/demo/stash_demo> git stash apply stash@{1}
fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: Did you use ´stash@{1}´, including the backticks? I recall `git stash apply` ignoring unknown stash names silently and just applying `stash@{0}` instead.

Comment: Yes I did include the backticks.

Comment: So, try it without them. ;)

Comment: I tried without the ticks it gives me an error saying its an ambiguous argument.I'll update the question the entire output its giving.

Comment: I noticed just now that when I apply the the stash@{1} with the backticks I get the message `stash@1: Command not found` and the most recent stash is applied.I think the syntax which I'm using is wrong.But if I try without he backticks nothing happens.

Comment: Finally worked after using doublequotes instead of backticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git's stash is (by default) a [LIFO storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29).

By using `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` you will always get the last stashed patch (which can be also referenced using `stash@{0}`, `0` is the index inside the stash). Stashing a new patch will place it on top of other stashed patches, thus increasing their indices by one (`stash@{0}` will become `stash@{1}`).

That said, if you want to apply or pop a patch other than the last one stashed, you need pass its ref to the command:

```
$ git stash apply stash@{1}
```

Comment: Even if I'm applying stash@{1} I'm getting the most recent changes applied to the repo.

Comment: Did you verify that `stash@{1}` is what you want? For example with `git stash list` or `git stash show stash@{1}`.

Comment: When I try `git stash show stash@{1}` and `git stash show stash@{0}` I'm getting the same output. And whatever I apply or pop I get the most recent changes.And even when I want `stash@{1}` i get the most recent changes.

Comment: That means that both `stash@{0}` and `stash@{1}` have the same content, so you might have stashed twice by mistake, e.g. using `git stash; git apply; git stash`. If you're sure the contents are the same, you can safely drop one of them: `git stash drop stash@{1}`.

Comment: No they are not same.First time I modified `a.txt` and stashed it.Later I modified `b.txt` and stashed it.Now when I list all the stashed contents I get the result that i have 2 stashes available.Now regardless of what I apply or pop I am getting `b.txt` applied then when i apply the other stash i get `a.txt`.Give me 2 mins and I will pate the entire log as edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

they are not mixed up!

Stashing stores the "commits" (not the correct word here, I know) in a Stack:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

so the operation pop always gets you the last thing you put in there.

This behaviour is by design

edit: if you need to flip something around, then pop each item in the stack(stash) individually - do a real commit - and interactive rebase or whatever ..

edit/edit: do a

```
git stash pop
```

then commit your changes (regardless of whether this commit is usefull or not)

then do a `git stash pop` again, commit again

now you can reorder or delete single commits - take a look here: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/20/reorder-commits-with-rebase.html
or search for interactive rebasing (again .. the next time do a branch this concept is much more powerfull then stashing)

Comment: Is there any way to get the first thing i stashed?

Comment: like i said (in the edit) pop everything seperately and do commits (maybe in a different branch - to be clean) then you will eventually end up with the first thing you stashed

Comment: btw: i realy prefer doing a quick branch over stashing because you have so much more control over everything..

Comment: The git stash apply stash@{n} has no meaning right, since it always pops/applies the most recent stash.I have added my workflow as an edit in the question

Comment: i tried to describe the solution a little better in the "edit/edit" part